# Чем декодировать response вида "\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! есть веб сайт, на нем данные на русском языке. скриптом получаю html, но русский текст там в таком виде:

```
\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f
```

Как мне его перевести в человеческий вид? а именно в русский текст? ЯП- Python 3.5.0

Comment: Каким образом вы этот «такой вид» увидели?

Comment: В пайтон 3 при выводе всё должно корректно отображаться без лишних манипуляций

Comment: тогда такой вопрос: если кроме слов, содержатся какие либо символы, которые нельзя декодировать- как от них избавиться?

Comment: @dimahimma вы так и не ответили, как вы этот «такой вид» вообще увидели, вот расскажите как вы его получаете, а там дальше разберёмся

Comment: @andreymal r=requests.get('mysite.com') r.text

Comment: А `print(r.text)` что выводит?

Comment: @andreymal UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 0: surrogates not allowed  Если взять одно слово на принт- нормально выводит, если всю строку- то ошибка. как я понял из за непереводимых символов в строке вроде этого \ud83d

Comment: Интересно, первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь. А если не секрет, можно узнать, что за сайт? Хочу сам потыкать

Comment: @andreymal видимо все из за того, что срока заключена в script type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```
str = '\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f'
print str.decode('unicode-escape')
```

Получаем

> Телеведущая

См. также

- [Описание метода str.decode (по-английски)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#str.decode)
- [Специальные кодировки Python (по-английски)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' python 3.5.0

Comment: @dimahimma тогда просто `print('\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f')`. Т.е. никак не нужно декодировать.

Comment: или заменить на `str = b'\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f'`

Comment: @gil9red SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.

Comment: @insolor SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 48-52: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: @dimahimma, если копировать из моего комментария, то да, там какие-то два лишних символа затесались, при вставке в текстовый редактор превращаются в вопросы. А если копировать из вашего вопроса, добавить кавычки, скобки и `print` в начало, то нормально выводится.

Comment: @dimahimma, вот попробуй: `print('\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f')` 
`print(b'\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f'.decode('unicode-escape'))`

Comment: да, с вашей помощью понял в чем беда: кроме просто слов, в тексте могут встречаться различные символы. если одно слово "телеведущая" питон нормально декодирует, то если встречаются какие либо непонятные символы- выдает ошибку UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 0: surrogates not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Для Python3 никаких манипуляций со строкой не нужно. Просто копирую из вопроса, добавляю кавычки и `print`, все выводится нормально:

```
>>> print('\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f')
Телеведущая
```

Comment: я бы еще добавил способ "трансформации": `new = str.__str__('\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0430\u044f')`

Comment: @MaxU, можно просто `new = str('\u0422\u0435\u043b...')`

Comment: действительно! что-то я сегодня "подтормаживаю"... :)